# How can i get address of virtual method , if I have pointer to base class object?

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, virtual

For example I have:

```
class A{
public:
virtual void run(){...}
};


class B:public A {
public:    void run(){...}
};


A* ptr= new B();
```

I only have a pointer 'ptr'.I know that pointer is type 'A*' but  I don't know whether it is pointing to object of the class 'A' or 'B' or some other class 'X' which is derived from class A and also implements function 'run'(in my example my object is type 'B').How could I get the address of the function 'run' that is implemented in the class of my object?

Comment: Why would you need to know it?

Comment: The address of the (actually going to be used) `run` function can only be found in the Virtual Table, which is normally not made visible to programmers. What precisely are you trying to accomplish by doing this: do you actually need the address of the function, or are you just looking for confirmation that the runtime-dispatching to the correct derived function is taking place?

Comment: do you want a function pointer or the address?

Comment: I am looking for the address.Or asking if it actually can be done .

Comment: @nikojov What you're directly trying to do can't be done. There are similar, tangential things that *can* be done, depending on your situation, but you need to explain your use-case for this kind of code, as without it, it's impossible to give you a useful answer.

Comment: @nikojov: this can be done in a compiler and platform dependent way, but please tell us first, what is your use case for this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `dynamic_cast`. 
You can `dynamic_cast` to the various derived class types and test if you get a valid pointer or `nullptr` back. That will let you determine the dynamic type of the object pointed to by your base class pointer.

Comment: Yeah,  but i don't get an address of the function, and I don't know names of all types.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there is no portable way of doing it.
Options:

1. Look up for vtbl by hand. It is NOT PORTABLE.
2. If you can change base class, try to force its users to provide you with necessary information
3. Can you write a wrapper of sort

```c++
void f(A *object) {
   object->run();
}
```

And use its address in place instead of an address of the actual run function?

Btw, what are you looking for? A pointer to a member function? A pointer to implementation? Just some address?